# Как работают несколько curl-запросов подряд?

Tags: php, curl

Работая с curl наткнулся на понимание того, что если инициализировать только один сеанс, и отправлять с него запросы на разные URL, то необязательно перед каждым запросом прописывать параметры. То-есть если прописать прокси перед первым запросом, он сохранится и для второго? Все ли параметры переносятся и на последующие запросы? Например, раньше я прописывал следующее:

```
/*Первый запрос*/
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $this->proxy_port);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, $this->proxytype);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->proxy_ip);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $this->loginpassw);
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);

/*Второй запрос*/
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $this->proxy_port);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, $this->proxytype);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->proxy_ip);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $this->loginpassw);
$result2 = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
```

То-есть каждый раз прописывал одно и тоже. Правильно я понимаю что повторяющиеся параметры можно прописать один раз и дальше они будут сохраняться для текущего сеанса?

Также есть вопрос по поводу получения результата запроса. Видел 2 варианта:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch); //Первый вариант

/*Второй вариант*/
curl_exec($ch);
$result = curl_multi_getcontent($ch);
```

Это одно и тоже? Либо есть какие-то различия?
Возможно надо было разделить эти вопросы в разные посты, но решил что это связано. Прошу помочь разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы используете `curl_init` вы открываете сеанс. Сеанс подразумевает, что вы выполняете какие-то действия, и пока вы его не закроете сеанс останется в том состоянии, которое вы для него задаете. Для завершения curl сеанса есть функция [curl_close](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-close.php). Как только вы выполните `curl_close($ch)`, все параметры указанного сеанса будут сброшены. Для создания запроса с новыми параметрами необходимо будет инициализировать сеанс снова.

Что касается второго вопроса: функции curl_multi* необходимы для многопоточного скачивания. Они нужны при инициализации нескольких одновременных сеансов. Подробнее про это можно почитать на [статье хабра](https://habr.com/ru/post/68175/) и в оф. документации php начиная с функции [curl_multi_init](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-multi-init.php). При обработке обычных запросов достаточно функции curl_exec.